# Jquery Click show content slide

Tags: jquery, html, magento

I working on magento . My task need to implement slide

I have one container have multiple item inside it. Each item have different content . This content have text , image (maybe need slider). In normal every content hidden. When user click on one of item . This content hidden change to showup. When click again this item , this content must be hidden again. In Case User click on another different item that previous content must be hidden and show new content

Anyone have solutions on this. Thanks to all

HTML Markup description below link pastebin

http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=VVDsX6d0
P/S i work on bootstrap latest version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at your link and you had a lot of excess code not needed for a mock up so i used some generic ids and classes, but you will find this does what you were looking for and very smoothly.

html

```
<div class="field">
    <a href="#" key="1">Content 1</a>
    <div id="toggleMe1" class="toggleMe">Some content</div>
</div>
<div class="field">
    <a href="#" key="2">Content 2</a>
    <div id="toggleMe2" class="toggleMe">Some more but different content</div>
</div>
<div class="field">
    <a href="#" key="3">Content 3</a>
    <div id="toggleMe3" class="toggleMe">and yet some more content</div>
</div>
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").on("click", function(){
        var dkey = $(this).attr("key");
        $(".toggleMe").each(function(){
            var opener = "toggleMe"+ dkey;
            if($(this).attr("id") == opener){
                $(this).slideDown(500);
            }else{
                $(this).slideUp(500);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

css

```
.toggleMe{
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    background:#e7e7e7;
    display:none;
}
.field{
    display:block;
}
a{
    background:#e7e7e7;
    color:#000;
    border:1px solid #000;
    padding:1px 8px;
    line-height:10px;
}
```

you can see it in action [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Base/6e9zkg1u/)

Im sure you can see what i did and how to transfer it into using your ids and classes.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Here try this

Html code:

```
<div class="office-row">
    <h3 class="office-title">Title</h3>
    <div class="office">sadasd</div>
  </div>
<div class="office-row">
    <h3 class="office-title">Title</h3>
    <div class="office">sadasd</div>
</div>
<div class="office-row">
    <h3 class="office-title">Title</h3>
    <div class="office">sadasd</div>
</div>
```

Jquery code:

```
$(function () {
$('.office-title').click(function () {
    $(this).next('div').slideToggle();

    $(this).parent().siblings().children().next().slideUp();
    return false;
});});
```

Css code:

```
.office{display: none;}
```

check this link : [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jubair/nR29B/5/)